# How to chain custom animations?

Tags: android, animation

```
    class SceneAnimation extends Animation{
public int x;
public ImageView mImageView;
public int[] mFrameRess;
public int[] mDurations;
public int mDuration;

public int mLastFrameNo;
public long mBreakDelay;

 public SceneAnimation(ImageView pImageView, int[] pFrameRess, int[] pDurations)
 {

    mImageView = pImageView;
    mFrameRess = pFrameRess;
    mDurations = pDurations;
    mLastFrameNo = pFrameRess.length - 1;

    play(1);
}

    public SceneAnimation(ImageView pImageView, int[] pFrameRess, int pDuration){
    mImageView = pImageView;
    mFrameRess = pFrameRess;
    mDuration = pDuration;
    mLastFrameNo = pFrameRess.length - 1;

    mImageView.setImageResource(mFrameRess[0]);
    playConstant(1);
}

    public SceneAnimation(ImageView pImageView, int[] pFrameRess, int pDuration, long pBreakDelay){            
    mImageView = pImageView;
    mFrameRess = pFrameRess;
    mDuration = pDuration;
    mLastFrameNo = pFrameRess.length - 1;
    mBreakDelay = pBreakDelay;

    mImageView.setImageResource(mFrameRess[0]);
    playConstant(1);
}


synchronized void play(final int pFrameNo)
{


    mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {


            mImageView.setImageResource(mFrameRess[pFrameNo]);
            if(pFrameNo == mLastFrameNo)
                {
                return;}
            else
                play(pFrameNo + 1);
        }
    }, mDurations[pFrameNo]);
}


public void playConstant(final int pFrameNo){
    mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {                    
            mImageView.setImageResource(mFrameRess[pFrameNo]);

            if(pFrameNo == mLastFrameNo)
                playConstant(0);
            else
                playConstant(pFrameNo + 1);
        }
    }, pFrameNo==mLastFrameNo && mBreakDelay>0 ? mBreakDelay : mDuration);
}



};
```

i can use this to play out alot of frames, i cant play one animation after the other or pause in between animations so im trying to figure out a way to use AnimationListener once i have instantiated this class

Comment: explain what you want to do in a better way. It's not clear. Do you want to trigger an event and notify a previously registered animation listener ? You want your component to fire animation events ?

Comment: Theres only 1 ImageView, if i make 2 SceneAnimation() and put them after one another in oncreate(), they play at the same time, im trying to make them play one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an AnimationListener as a field of your class, add a setter. Then other classes can add a listener to your SceneAnimation.

After that, create a method fireFooEvent to fire events to your listener if its not null.

Then use those fire methods inside your SceneAnimation class to notify a potential listener of the beginning and the end of your animation.

Next, inside your activity, add a listener to the first animation, start it. And when the listener will receive the end of the first animation, start the second animation.

---UPDATED WITH SOME CODE

```
public void setAnimationLIstener( AnimationListener listener ) {
 this.animationListener = listener;
}

public void fireOnAnimationEnd(Animation animation)() {
 if( this.animationListener == null ) {
    return;
 }
 this.animationListener.onAnimationEnd(animation);
}
```

And do this for every event. Then you can easily notifier listeners of what happens in your AnimationScene object.

Comment: add a setter and fireFooEvent

Comment: put that in the SceneAnimation class?

Comment: where the animation ends in SceneAnimation put animationListener = null, does that tell the listener that the animation is over?

Comment: i got it, thanks for your time, 48hrs straight searching for this solution

Comment: Nice ! By the way, you just implemented the Oberser - Observable design pattern : http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-1996/jw-10-howto.html or http://www.siteduzero.com/forum-83-350466-p1-pattern-observer-observable.html